# How to check socket status from other classes in android?

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

can anyone help me how to check wifi socket status i.e whether it connected or not from  other class/other class of service. if it not connected then how to connect to server.
as well as how to check whether wifi is enable or not, if not then how to enable wifi from other service class.

```js
package com.example.pci.calling;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static   ToggleButton WiFiONOFFButton,ConnectWiFi;
     WifiManager wifi;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    String networkSSID = "EasyControl";
    String networkPass = "easy1234";

    static Button Asend,Vsend,Dsend,Connect;


    static    InputStream nis;
    static    OutputStream nos;

    static public      Socket socket;
    EditText editSend;
    static   TextView receivedata,Status;
    public    static Boolean socket_connect=false;
    public    static Boolean wifi_connect=false;

    TextView textInfo;


    final Context context = this;
    Dialog dialog;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntentOn,pendingIntentOff;
    Calendar calOn,calOff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConnectWiFi = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.connectwifi);
        WiFiONOFFButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect1);
        Vsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVsend);
        Dsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDsend);
        Asend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAsend);


        editSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSend);
        Status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        receivedata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        wifi.startScan();



        ConnectWiFi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {


                    MyClienttask outer = new MyClienttask();
                    outer
                            .execute();


                } else {

                    try {
                        nis.close();
                        nos.close();
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        Vsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    datasend();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });


        Vsend.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                timer();
                Intent myIntentOn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmDetails.class);
                pendingIntentOn = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntentOn, 0);
                Intent myIntentoff = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmDetailsoff.class);
                pendingIntentOff = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntentoff, 0);

                return false;
            }
        });

        if (wifi_connect==true){
            wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        }
    }



    void datasend() throws IOException
    {
        nos.write("V".getBytes());
    }

    public void timer(){

        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Set Prefer Time And Date");

        final RadioButton RadiobuttonOn = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_radio_dialog_on);
        final RadioButton RadiobuttonOff = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_radio_dialog_off);
        Button dialogOKbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_ok);
        Button dialogCANCELbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_cancel);
        final EditText txttime = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time);
        final EditText txtdate = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date);
        final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(RadiobuttonOn.isChecked()==true) {

            txtdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //  Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                    mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calOn = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
                            calOn.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                            calOn.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                            calOn.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                            txtdate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
                    mDatePicker.show();

                }
            });

            txttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Calendar mycalender = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = newCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = newCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            txttime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);

                            calOn.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                            calOn.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                            calOn.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                    mTimePicker.show();
                }
            });

        }
        if (RadiobuttonOff.isChecked()==true){

            txtdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //  Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
                    mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calOff = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
                            calOff.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                            calOff.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                            calOff.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                            txtdate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
                    mDatePicker.show();

                }
            });

            txttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Calendar mycalender = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = newCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = newCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            txttime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);

                            calOff.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                            calOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                            calOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                    mTimePicker.show();
                }
            });

        }



        dialogOKbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmDetails.class);
                //   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                if (RadiobuttonOn.isChecked()==true) {
                    //   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmDetails.class);
                    //   pendingIntentOn = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calOn.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOn);
                }
                if (RadiobuttonOff.isChecked()==true) {
                    //    Intent myIntentoff = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmDetailsoff.class);
                    //    pendingIntentOff = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntentoff, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calOn.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentOff);
                }





            }
        });
        dialogCANCELbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (RadiobuttonOn.isChecked()==true){
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntentOn);
                }
                if (RadiobuttonOff.isChecked()==true){
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntentOff);
                }




            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }



    public class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wireless = wifi.getScanResults(); // Returns a <list> of scanResults
            for (ScanResult scan : wireless) {
                if (scan.SSID.equals("EasyControl")) {
                    boolean cont = true;
                    // WiFiONOFFButton.setChecked(true);

                    if (cont) {
                        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
                        wc.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
                        wc.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);
                        wc.hiddenSSID = true;
                        wc.priority = 1;
                        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

                        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

                        int netid = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
                        wifi.enableNetwork(netid, true);
                        wifi.reconnect();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

 /*   public  void disableWifi(Context context,  Boolean bool) {
      //  WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(bool)
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        else
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);


    public static boolean IsWiFiConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getTypeName().equals("WIFI")
                            && info[i].isConnected())
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    } }*/


}
```

In MyClienttask

```js
package com.example.pci.calling;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class MyClienttask extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Void> {

    String dstAddress = "192.168.4.1";
    int dstPort = 666;
    String response = "";



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

         MainActivity.socket = null;

        try {
            MainActivity.socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            if (MainActivity.socket.isConnected()) {
                MainActivity.socket_connect=true;
                //    Connect();
                //  Connect.setText("Disconnect");
            MainActivity.    nis = MainActivity.socket.getInputStream();
           MainActivity.     nos = MainActivity.socket.getOutputStream();
          MainActivity.      nos.write("A".getBytes());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read =MainActivity. nis.read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                while (read != -1) {
                    byte[] tempdata = new byte[read];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, tempdata, 0, read);
                    publishProgress(new byte[][]{tempdata});
                    read = MainActivity.nis.read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                }
                //    datasend2();

            } else {
                MainActivity.socket_connect=false;
                //  Disconnect();
                // Status.setText("Disconnected");
                // btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (MainActivity.socket != null) {
                try {
                    MainActivity. socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
        String toReceive;// = new String();

        try {
            toReceive = new String(values[0], "ISO-8859-1");
            MainActivity.receivedata.setText(toReceive);


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In AlarmDetails

```js
package com.example.pci.calling;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class AlarmDetails extends Service {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Boolean stage =false;
    // flag for Internet connection status
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

    String networkSSID = "EasyControl";
    String networkPass = "easy1234";
    WifiScanReceiver   wifiReciever;


    // Connection detector class
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    WifiManager wifi;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        MainActivity.Vsend.setText("OnCreate");


     //   cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    //    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        //   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //   PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// build notification
// the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short








    }



    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return null;

    }







    @Override

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){

           MainActivity. wifi_connect=false;
        }else{
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 800ms



                }
            }, 100000);
           // MainActivity. wifi_connect=true;

        }

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 800ms

                wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
                wifi.startScan();

            }
        }, 100000);

        if (MainActivity.ConnectWiFi.isChecked()) {
            //  MainActivity.ConnectWiFi.setChecked(true);
            Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 800ms


                    MainActivity.Vsend.setText("OnStart");
                    MainActivity.Vsend.performClick();
                }
            }, 1000);


        }else {
            MainActivity.ConnectWiFi.performClick();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 800ms


                    MainActivity.Vsend.setText("OnStart1");
                    MainActivity.Vsend.performClick();
                    stage=true;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

   /*     if (isInternetPresent) {
            MainActivity.Asend.setText("Hoche");
        }else{
            MainActivity.Asend.setText("Onno Vabe");
        }*/

        if (MainActivity.socket_connect == true){
            MainActivity.Asend.setText("Hoche");
        }else{
            MainActivity.Asend.setText("Onno Vabe");
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        // .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.btswon)
                        .setContentTitle("My Notification Title")
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setContentText("Something interesting happened");
        int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 800ms
                if(stage==false){
                    MainActivity.ConnectWiFi.setChecked(true); stopSelf();
                }else{
                    MainActivity.ConnectWiFi.setChecked(false); stopSelf();
                }


            }
        }, 1000);




    }



    @Override

    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }


    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onDestroy();



        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MainActivity.Vsend.setText("Done");




    }

    public class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wireless = wifi.getScanResults(); // Returns a <list> of scanResults
            for (ScanResult scan : wireless) {
                if (scan.SSID.equals("EasyControl")) {
                    boolean cont = true;
                    // WiFiONOFFButton.setChecked(true);

                    if (cont) {
                        WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
                        wc.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
                        wc.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPass);
                        wc.hiddenSSID = true;
                        wc.priority = 1;
                        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

                        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                        wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                        wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                        wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

                        int netid = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
                        wifi.enableNetwork(netid, true);
                        wifi.reconnect();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

is this possible from ****public class AlarmDetails extends Service**** 
1.to connect specific wifi AP.
2. using Alarm Manager I want to send some data to server, at that time how could i know thus my mobile connected with specific SSID, if not how to connect from **public class AlarmDetails extends Service** class

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConnectivityManager to check if wifi is connected or not, you would have to add permission in your manifiest file:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (isWifi) {

            }
```

Permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Ok... this code i put in service class? and what about socket whether it connected or not......

Comment: what do you mean by socket ?

Comment: Socket  mean when a  wifi client connect to the server, how could i know they are connected to each other or not....

Comment: please share your code. Otherwise it's impossible to answer any further.